# Edit button in some files in bitbucket is disabled

Tags: bitbucket

Edit button in some files in bitbucket is disabled.

for example:

[image]

but in this repo, I can edit other files.

Like this:

[image]

I cannot understand the reason.

Comment: Any chance you have an actual link for me (or others) to have a look at?

Comment: I cannot send link to you because in our network we have it.

Comment: Whatever the issue is, it's specific to Bitbucket. Git itself does not store a write-permission bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check file encoding.

I had the same problem before. Check tooltip on the Edit button.

**My error:**

> This file contains characters that indicate problems with encoding and
> can't be edited